# Calling two different activities on different devices (tablet and phone)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Here, I'm trying to start an activity on different devices (Android Tablet and Android Phone). Is there a way to use if statement to check which activity should to load based on the devices?
Here's my code:

```
Button buttonGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_goToActivity);
         buttonGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (tablet device) {
                     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabletActivity.class));
                 } else {
                     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidPhoneActivity.class));
             }
         });
```

Thanks for your effort...

Comment: What are the differences between these two activities?

Comment: TabletActivity is used to large screen like tablet and two-pane layout. And AndroidPhoneActivity is used to small screen and non two-pane layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve that you must use `Fragment` not an `Activity`. the [Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design) of `Fragments` is exactly what you want. you can take a look at [Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example) to see how it is implemented. This is a master-detail app with two `Fragments`, when device in a portrait mode or it is **not** a tablet it just shows master, otherwise it also shows detail beside the master and when you select an item from the list you will see the details without going to other `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly as Android Best Practice it is adviced to use Fragments rather than Activity to achieve your requirement.

But if you are keen on using Activity, then below is the solution to find device type and load  different activities.

1) Have 2 values folders: values -> strings.xml and values-sw600dp -> strings.xml

2) Create string value in both the xml

```
<string name="device_type">PHONE</string> in values -> strings.xml
<string name="device_type">TABLET</string> in values-sw600dp -> strings.xml
```

3) create a method to check if current device is Phone or not

```
public boolean isPhone() {
   String deviceType = getResource().getString(R.string.device_type);

   if (deviceType.equalsIgnoreCase("PHONE") {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   } 
}
```

4) Depending on the device load your activity as you have already done in your above code snippet

Let me know if this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you should **not** have two separate activities here. Instead, you should have two different **layouts** for the same activity. The layout for phones should be in the regular `res/layout` folder and the layout for tablets should be in the `res/layout-large` folder. Read [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same fuctionality for Tablet Activity and Phone activity then you do not need two activities for this purpose. You need to make two different Layout xml for Tablet as well as Phone.

1. Make a Layout folder named : layout-large and layout-xlarge.
2. Now copy the xml file from normal layout folder and paste in both new layout folders.
3. No need to change the name of xml file.
4. Now Adjust xml file of layout-large and layot-xlarge as you want to make design for tablet.
5. Now on running application Tablet and phone bot will pick xml according to there size and screen density.

   Note : the functionality should be same.

**And if:**  you want to show different screen with different functionality for phone and tablet then. use this code for check.

```
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
    

   }
```

Hope this wll help you.